# React Todo App I get an error while converting class components to functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, thank you in advance for your help. While making Todo App, I made adding and removing operations into functional components, but I could not make other components. I would be glad if you could help.

**TodoItem.js**: *(I tried a lot but could not make it functional due to errors.)*

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title } = this.props.todo // I did not understand here what it does.

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)} // and here too
          />
          {""} {title}{" "}
          <button onClick={this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, id)}>X </button>{" "}
        </p>{" "}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Addtodo.js**: *(I converted it to functional but it doesn't list the input I wrote.)*

```
const Addtodo = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("")

  const onSubmit = (e) => {  // I made a mistake here, I don't know why there is a problem.
    e.preventDefault()
    setTitle("")
  }

  const onChange = (e) => setTitle(e.target.value)

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={onChange}
        value={title}
        placeholder="Add todo"
      />
      <input type="Submit" value="Submit" className="btn" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

**App.js component**: *(I was able to make them functional. I would be glad if you can check it.)*

```
const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => setTodos(res.data))
  }, [])

  const markComplete = (id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })
    )
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then((res) => setTodos([...todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)]))
  }

  // Add Todo
  const Addtodo = (title) => {
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
        title,
        completed: false
      })
      .then((res) => setTodos([...todos, res.data]))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container"> 
        <Header />
        <AddTodo Addtodo={Addtodo} /> // I think I made a mistake here with the props.
        <Todo
          todos={todos}
          markComplete={markComplete}
          deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
        />{" "}
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting

Comment: May be you could see this sample app https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-upf3dz?file=src%2FTodoItem.js

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between your definition of the AddTodo component, and then adding your AddTodo component to the DOM. In Addtodo.js, you've got the function signature as:

```
const Addtodo = () => {
```

Therefore the Addtodo component is not expecting any props to be passed into it.

In App.js, you try to add the component to the DOM with:

```
<AddTodo Addtodo={Addtodo} />
```

So you're asking the component to be rendered with a prop called Addtodo, but as stated earlier, in the component's definition, it's not expecting to receive any props.

You need to decide whether or not you want / need the AddTodo component to receive props.

If you want it to receive the AddTodo prop, you can change the function definition to:

```
const Addtodo = ({ AddTodo }) => {
```

Also, make sure that when you export the Addtodo component, you export it as a default export, as the casing is currently inconsistent in your code (defined as Addtodo, but tried to render as AddTodo in App.js). If this is a default export though, it doesn't matter too much. Make sure your import statement for the AddTodo is the same as when you render AddTodo.

To be explicit, make sure you have `export default Addtodo` in Addtodo.js
Make sure the import statement for the add todo component is the same. So, if the top of App.js says `import AddTodo from './Addtodo'`, then when you render the component later in the file, it is done like `<AddTodo />`. And if the import was `import Addtodo from './Addtodo'`, then the component is rendered as `<Addtodo>` (casing must be consistent)

I apologise if that wasn't the clearest explanation, I'm unsure of what the actual terms for some of the things I referred to are, but I hope you got what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the onSubmit function from the form element and use it with onClick in the button element. Give it a try. I think it will work.